# Output the variables in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I am struggling to get the output of the power shell in my azure pipeline.
I have tried sending it in multiple directories. None have produced the desired result.
Echo works and i can see all the information. Now i would like to save that data and place it as a file in working directory before the artifact is built.

Never done this before so not entirely sure if this is a right approach either.

[Vars echo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbKde.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to output pipeline variables to txt file in Powershell.

You can try to use the following PowerShell script:

```
"Bucket name = $(Bucketname), Bucket arn =  $(Bucketarn)" | out-file  -filepath $(build.sourcesdirectory)\vars.txt -append -width 200
```

For example:

```
variables:
  Bucketname: 'test1'
  Bucketarn: 'test2'

steps:
- powershell: '"Bucket name = $(Bucketname), Bucket arn =  $(Bucketarn)" | out-file  -filepath $(build.sourcesdirectory)\vars.txt -append -width 200'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

Result:

[image]